Ideal of multivariate polynomial
Let $p(x_1,...,x_n)$ be an element of $\mathbb{F}_2[x_1,...,x_n]/(x_1^2+1,...,x_n^2+1)$. Is there a way to capture the size or dimension of the ideal $(p(x))$? I would guess that if there is a way, it would involve the degrees of the constituent monomials? I can figure out some special cases, including dimensions $2^n$ and $2^{n-1}$, but not the general one.

If I find the time, I will think about this a bit more. The one thing I will certainly do before I try anything else is to make the substitution $x_i\mapsto x_i+1$ for all $i$. This is because $x_i^2+1=(x_i+1)^2$. Meaning that your quotient ring is isomorphic to
$$\Bbb{F}_2[x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n]/\langle x_1^2,x_2^2,\ldots,x_n^2\rangle.$$ That way of looking at it just feels simpler.

With the rewriting of the previous comment in place we see that $p$ is a unit if it has a non-zero constant term. Another isomorphism allows us assume that the linear part of   $p$ (if any) is equal to $x_1$, but then it bifurcates. This is more difficult than I expected :-)

Yes, indeed. It appears as an innocent question at first :)
